# Rename user name iSQL plus

Tags: rename

I was wondering how you would change the name of a username in iSQL plus. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one table (which is a terrible assumption)

The sql query is 
UPDATE USER SET username=newuser WHERE username=oldusername

Comment: Could you explain it in terms of what I have to change it to.
Current username = developer_xx
and I want to change the username to xxx1234_developer.
I have already created multiple tables.
Thanks

Comment: Oh wait, I'm not exactly changing a username so much, but I just need to rename the username I have given for the developer, as well as the dba of the database.